# Why is the »_builtin« parameter not advised in »register_post_type()« for custom post types?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, user-registration, customization

The parameter `"_builtin" => true` is a huge help for me, as this will set good permalink structure, like standard posts, for example:

`example.com/my_category/sub_category/`**`POST-NAME`**
instead of 
`example.com/`**`POST-NAME`**

But in documentation, it is not advised - [see note](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#_builtin):

> Note: this Codex entry is for documentation - core developers recommend you don't use this when registering your own post type

Why?

May I rely on that, and start building my site with it? or it will be removed soon?

Comment: what does "as this will set good permalink structure, like standard posts" mean?

Comment: @milo I have updated my question. I described all details.

Answer (score 1):

I'd figure, it mainly is not advised, because it is intended just to use it for built-in post types, just because you can use for custom post types it does not change anything on that intention.

For example, if you use it and there are changes in WordPress that make that arguments use strictly available for built-in post types, then you are in trouble.

And, no, its not going to be removed soon - if ever, it likely will die with WordPress.